# check box depending input fields cannot reset after uncheck

Tags: javascript, php

I create a checkbox and its 2 depending input fields, when I check the check box 2 input fields appear then I write some in that but when I unchecked the checkbox that input fields cannot reset that value and submitted forward. I want simple when I uncheck then check box its depending input fields reset their values to default. Here is my code:

```
<input id="return" type="checkbox" value="" name="return">Return Journey 
<div class="bkt_return_journey" id="altway" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="datebr" id="datepickerr" class="booktaxti_input"  /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#return').live('change', function(){

 if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
     $('#altway').show();
 } else {
     $('#altway').hide();
 }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="return" type="checkbox" value="" name="return">Return Journey 
    <div class="bkt_return_journey" id="altway" style="display: none;">
     <input type="text" name="datebr" id="datepickerr" class="booktaxti_input"  />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#return').on('click', function(){

          if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('#datepickerr').val('');
             $('#altway').show();
         } else {
             $('#altway').hide();
         }
         });
    });


     </script>
</body>
```

hope it could help you out

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="return" type="checkbox" value="" name="return">Return Journey 
<div class="bkt_return_journey" id="altway" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="datebr" id="datepickerr" class="booktaxti_input"  /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','#return', function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $('#altway').show();   
    } else {
        $('#altway').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: this work try this . on click text box show and on uncheck it hide

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as follow:

```
$('#return').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#datepickerr').val('');
        $('#altway').show();
    } else {
        $('#altway').hide();
    }
});
```